# Handle listview item height?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So i have this script which is build a listview

```
class NewProductsLists extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<NewProducts> newlist;

  NewProductsLists({Key key, this.newlist}) : super(key: key);
  final formatCurrency =
  new NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: "id", decimalDigits: 2);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: newlist.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print("Product detail");
                },
                child: Card(
                  child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.50,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.network(
                              Configuration.url +
                                  "assets/app_assets/" +
                                  newlist[index].productImage,
                              width: 90,
                              height: 90,
                              filterQuality: FilterQuality.low),
                          ListTile(
                            title: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  newlist[index].productName,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                )),
                            subtitle: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  formatCurrency.format(
                                      int.parse(newlist[index].productPrice)),
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 15),
                                )),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                ),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

and the result looks like this

[[image: result[1]]

As you can see the card is expanding so hard. I know it is because the Expanded widget. Is it possible to make the card `wrap_content` ?

Comment: You can set a fixed height by adding itemExtend: to your ListView.builder

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal list view needs fixed height if its not going to be vertical scrollable view you can use Expanded widget with varying flex to get it working.

Working build widget by using expanded widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          centerTitle: false,
          title: const Text('November'),
        ),
        body: new Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(flex: 1,child:  new Container(color: Colors.grey[300],),),
                Expanded(flex: 2,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 10,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            print("Product detail");
                          },
                          child: Card(
                            child: Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.50,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Image.network(
                                        'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png',
                                        width: 90,
                                        height: 90,
                                        filterQuality: FilterQuality.low),
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                        'item Name ${index}',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                      )),
                                      subtitle: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                        '\$10',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.red, fontSize: 15),
                                      )),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
                new Expanded(flex: 3,child:  new Container(color: Colors.amber[100],),),
              ],
            )));
  }
```

Result screen
[image: sample image]

Let me know if it suits your requirement.